# Buttons and auto layout: two things... two problems

Tags: ios, xcode9, ios-autolayout

Look at this image, please :

[image]

1' problem: i'd like to build it in iPhone SE, 8, 8 Plus and X but i can't do it.

2' problem: I used image and text insets to place the central image above the text. Changing the iPhone devise, and changing the proporsions of the buttons, also changes the arrangement of text and image?

Thank you.

Comment: I would consider using a `UIStackView` in `horizontal` mode to contain the image and text.  You could then add these to additional `UIStackView` views to generate a grid, eventually allowing you to constraint the outer most `UIStackView` to the centre of the super view.  From there you can generate traits for different devices/layouts or manipulate the constraints directly

Comment: Use stackview 's ok, but it have't  effects when touched

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1' problem: i'd like to build it in iPhone SE, 8, 8 Plus and X but i can't do it.
=> why ? what 's your problem?
2':Use stackview 's ok, but it have't effects when touched. You can create a CustomButton class :

```
class ImageTopButton: UIButton
{
    override func layoutSubviews()
    {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        let size = self.frame.size
        let imageSize = self.imageView!.intrinsicContentSize
        let labelSize = self.titleLabel!.intrinsicContentSize

        let totalHeight = imageSize.height + labelSize.height
        let heightDiff = size.height - totalHeight
        let padding = heightDiff / 2
        let verticalPading:CGFloat = 10

        self.imageView!.center = CGPoint(x: size.width / 2, y: imageSize.height / 2 + padding - verticalPading/2)
        self.titleLabel!.center = CGPoint(x: size.width / 2, y: imageSize.height + padding + labelSize.height / 1.5 + verticalPading/2)
    }
}
```

You can change verticalPading and set class for UIButton is `ImageTopButton`
whatever for 1': 
[image]

[image]

[image]
hope it's useful

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: When I switch to iphone SE, truncate the text. Is there a way to adapt it to the new resolution?

Comment: add 
        self.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
to layoutSubviews of ImageTopButton

Answer (score 0):

Start with a `UIImageView` and `UILabel`.  Constraint the width (or height) to your desired value (this is what you will use to change the size of the image later). Add a "aspect ratio constraint" to the `UIImageView` and constraint it appropriately (I've used a ratio/multiplier of `1:1`, you will need to calculate it based on your original image

[image: Container view][image: Starting point]

Select both the `UIImageView` and `UILabel` and "wrap" in a `UIStackView`

[image: Wrap in StackView]

Adjust the properties of the `UIStackView` to your needs

[image: StackView properties]

I used the above to allow the text or image to grow larger without constraining the other element

Okay, the fun part.  Copy and paste the `UIStackView`, align the second `UIStackView` below the first, so it generates a "column".  Select both and wrap in another `UIStackView`

[image: Multiple StackViews]

Update the properties of the new `UIStackView`...

[image: Properties]

Again, I'm focusing on allowing each group to expand without constraining the other

And now I have a container that looks something like...

[image: Container View]

Okay, now copy this new `UIStackView` and paste it, align to the trailing edge (it's not important, but it will make it easier to describe) - this will give you a 2x2 grid.  Select the two top most `UIStackView`s and, again, wrap in another `UIStackView`

[image: Lots more]

Again, I modified the `UIStackView` properties to `Aligment` to `Center` and `Distribution` to `Equal Centering`

Okay, now for some fun.  Select three of the `UIImageView`s (personally, I use the top/left one as the master) and remove their constraints (you can use the "Selected View/Clear Constraints option)

[image: Clear Constraints]

Select one of the "clean" `UIImageView`s and <kbd>Control</kbd>+Drag to the "master" `UIImageView` and add width and height constraints, so they will be equal to the master's

[image: Constrain width/height]

*hint-* You can hold down Command to select multiple constraints

Repeat for the other two "clean" `UIImageView`s

I would know constraint the top most `UIStackView` to the center of the view, or you can constrain it in any other way you want, but this makes it the primary anchor.

## Okay, but why?

Well, now you only need to update a single constraint to update all the images!

Try it.  Select the "master" `UIImageView`, find it's `width` constraint (you might need to go to the properties sheet) and change it's constant to something else.  All the `UIImageView`s should update!

[image: Equal scaling]

At this point, I'd be binding this constraint to the `UIViewController` so you can modify it within code.

## Why stack the stacks this way?

That's a good question, you choices might differ, but, I choose to construct it this way so that the columns will remain entered with each other if the text values are different widths.

[image: Some long text]

## Is there a simpler way?

Oh, how I wish!  Okay, this isn't a "bad" solution, but it does take some thought and about how to lay it out and don't ask me what will happen if the text is split over multiple lines - because it's not pretty.

A "different" approach might be to use a `UIView` or a container view and then trying to generate the constraints between the images (horizontal and vertical alignment) and the constraint the text between the images in some meaningful way, but that becomes really complex really fast...

Then how do you align them to the parent view?  This is why I'd use either a `UIView` or container view, but then it becomes more complicated as you need to stop the API defining it's own constraints and make sure that you have the correct constraints for the top, bottom, leading and trailing edges

What happens when the text is longer/shorter then the images?!  So if you only have some basic text, then the above should work reasonable well and should reasonably maintainable.

Comment: Can I use images created as buttons?

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: Conceptually, you can use what ever combination of views you want